# Line break ignoring regex to find package name in manifest file

Tags: java, regex, osgi, manifest

Consider the following manifest file as an example:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1418226794711
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_67
Built-By: ubuntu
Bundle-Description: Camel FTP support
Bundle-DocURL: http://www.apache.org/
Bundle-License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: camel-ftp
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-ftp
Bundle-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Bundle-Version: 2.14.1
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: org.apache.camel.component.file.remote;uses:="com.jcraft
 .jsch,org.slf4j,org.apache.camel.util,org.apache.camel.component.file,o
 rg.apache.camel,org.apache.commons.net.ftp,org.apache.camel.spi,org.apa
 che.camel.util.jsse,javax.net.ssl,org.apache.camel.impl,org.apache.came
 l.processor.idempotent";version="2.14.1",org.apache.camel.component.fil
 e.remote.strategy;uses:="org.apache.camel.util,org.apache.camel.compone
 nt.file,org.apache.camel,org.apache.commons.net.ftp,org.slf4j,org.apach
 e.camel.component.file.strategy,com.jcraft.jsch";version="2.14.1"
Export-Service: org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver;component=ftp,org
 .apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver;component=ftps,org.apache.camel.spi
 .ComponentResolver;component=sftp
Implementation-Title: Apache Camel
Implementation-Version: 2.14.1
Import-Package: com.jcraft.jsch;version="[0.1.40,0.2)",javax.net.ssl,org
 .apache.camel;version="[2.14,2.15)",org.apache.camel.component.file;ver
 sion="[2.14,2.15)",org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy;version="[2
 .14.1,2.14.2)",org.apache.camel.impl;version="[2.14,2.15)",org.apache.c
 amel.processor.idempotent;version="[2.14,2.15)",org.apache.camel.spi;ve
 rsion="[2.14,2.15)",org.apache.camel.util;version="[2.14,2.15)",org.apa
 che.camel.util.jsse;version="[2.14,2.15)",org.apache.commons.net.ftp;ve
 rsion="[3.3,4)",org.slf4j;version="[1.6,2)"
Karaf-Info: Camel;camel-ftp=2.14.1
Tool: Bnd-1.50.0
```

During hunting for dependency problems it is quite common for me to search for a specific package in the manifests of my projects. However because of the line breaks it is quite difficult to find them. For example if I would look for *org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.strategy* as simple text, it would not be found, since there is a line break after *org.apache.camel.component.fil*.

**Can you imagine any regular expression** which can be used to search for a text ignoring line breaks at any position? Is it possible with regexes? Please provide an example regex to find *org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.strategy*! Is there any alternative  solution to easily search in manifests?

Answer (score 3):

Why do not you use the [Manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/Manifest.html) class to process a MANIFEST file? You can use the constructor that accepts an InputStream.

After the Manifest is parsed, you can get the specific attributes you need (I guess Export-Package in your case).

Again, if you use regular expressions, you might have a mistake that you find a package in one of the attributes or directives of an Export-Package clause (e.g.: in the uses directive). Therefore I recommend that you should use the [felix utils](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.apache.felix.utils) library to parse each clause.

An example:

```
String searchedPackageName = "org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.strategy";

Manifest manifest = new Manifest(streamOfTheManifest);
String exportPackageHeader = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Export-Package");

// Parser and clause comes from org.apache.felix.utils.manifest package
Clause[] clauses = Parser.parseHeader(exportPackageHeader);

for (Clause exportPackageClause : clauses) {
    String exportedPackageName = exportPackageClause.getName();
    if (searchedPackageName.equals(exportedPackageName) {
    // Do your stuff here
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that parsing the manifest would work. I just need a command line tool or some fast way to look for manifests in a folder. Of course I could write one, but that is not my first intention :)

Comment: I am not sure a regular expression can be written where line break can occure at any time. Also, there would be too many specialties that you should take care of if you want to handle all the syntax rules a clause can have. Even if you could write such a regex, I think that would work slowly (regexes are not always fast). Manifest class is already in Java and felix utils is often used in the way that its necessary classes are simply copied out. I would suggest that you should do that as well and you can have a runnable console application without any dependency (and it would be fast enough)

Comment: For manifest parsing I do not need Felix. Simple JDK classes would do the job. Hmm. Yep to parse the values it still looks like useful.

Comment: Yes. If you do not use the HeaderParser of felix utils, you will have an issue, that you might find a package name in the uses directive or in any custom attribute. By parsing the clause, you can avoid these issues. I do not think that parser is slow as it runs through the header, sets flags and separates the data.

Answer (score 1):

Take your search term and

- escape the RegEx special chars e.g. . -> \.
- add "\s*" between all characters

and make sure to run your RegEx with dotall and Multiline.

Very nice tool for RegEx development is the eclipse plugin at http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickrex/

Searching in Manifests can be achieved via a small FileSearch library I wrote. This allows cmd line execution "java -jar ...". Purpose of this lib was initially exactly your task description - dependency research inside bundles and their MANIFEST.MF files.
Source is here https://github.com/peterkir/klib.io

Comment: I also like Quickrex. I will give a try to your project, thank you. I come back to you later.